# Post decrement, what is a-- * a--?

Tags: java, decrement

> ```java
> int a = 10;
> System.out.println(a-- * a--);
> ```
>
> what will be the output of these print statement and why??

in post decrement we actually observe that

- the value is used before getting change

but here I am getting in one of the operator (a--) is  10 and in another operator (a--) with which we are multiplying is getting 9.

overall the output which I came across is 100 but the actual output is 90

please explain how?

Comment: "the value is used before getting change" exactly - the value still changes. Why did you expect the value to stay at 10, when the second `a--` is run?

Comment: The real-world output is "your pull request is rejected; reformulate that expression for clarity".

Comment: The operands used in a multiplication are evaluated left to right. Evaluating the left `a--` yields 10 as you expected and decrements `a` to 9. Now I leave to you what happens when the right operands is evaluated. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Java sees `A * B`, so it first needs to compute both arguments, A and B.

The left operand (A) `a--` is executed, making `a = 9`, but **returning the value it had before**, so `10`.

We now have `10 * a--`. Next, Java executes the right operand (B) and we get `a = 8`, but we use the value it had before the decrement, so `9`.

We get `10 * 9`, which is `90`. And `a = 8`.

Comment: "_but **returning** the value it had before_" - Should that read "_but **using** the value it had before_"? As in the value _used_ in the multiplication is `10`.

Comment: Never mind. It's returned so it can be used.

Comment: Essentially, the expression `a--` (with a = 10), has the side-effect of making `a = 9` and then evaluating to `10`. While `--a` has the same side-effect, but evaluates to `9`.